# Protect Shopify Theme from Crack/Leak

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

I want create a shopify theme for sell on shopify store but how i can protect it from crack ?

Thank you

Hi, I have try nothing atm

Comment: You can't, this is not how it works. You can bundle JS files but it will only make sales harder for you. Merchants prefer themes that they can modify.

Answer (score 1):

There is not Specific way to do it. Once the theme is installed, it is moved to the Shopify admin with all the Liquid files and assets. So that, owner can edit it.

One idea I can think of is, you can bundle compressed JS and load it via your Own server. **BUT, I don't recommend it,** as this will completely destroy the modification structure of the theme.

**Instead, I suggest,** you keep the theme code simple and clean with high quality code, so that any developer can easily modify it as per clients need as most of the clients, who buy themes, what to modify it at some point as per their requirements. This can in turn, will make your theme more likely to get sold as you'll receive better ratings and feedback.

Hope this help. :)